# How to provide password when running horizon db migrate up command inside docker container?

Tags: horizon, docker, new-developer, postgres

I have issues with horizon, when inside the docker container I run `horizon db clear` and I get the output

````
There are 18 migrations to apply in the "up" direction.

...

2019/06/20 10:44:26 A database migration is required to run this version (v0.18.0) of Horizon. Run "horizon db migrate up" to update your DB.```

but when I run `horizon db migrate up` I get 
```pq: password authentication failed for user "root"
````

What does this mean?  What password would there be for running commands as the default user inside the container?

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this issue today. I was able to check what the `DATABASE_URL` value that cmd `horizon db migrate up` expected by looking at `horizon.env` within the stellar/quickstart docker container. I then ran the command `export DATABASE_URL=postgres://stellar:mypass@localhost/horizon && horizon db migrate up` and migration was successful. Seems the env vars in `horizon.env` do not work as intended if you have a custom password set.